# Qual a regência do verbo entregar?

Tags: gramática, verbos, regência

Gostaria de saber como é feita a regência do verbo ***entregar***, alguém poderia me ajudar com isto?

Comment: Essa informação podes vê-la num dicionário como o Aulete: http://www.aulete.com.br/entregar

Answer (score 2):

Os exemplos e definições são retirados da 45.ª ed. do *Dicionário de Verbos e Regimes* de Fransisco Fernandes (citações omitidas):

#### *entregar<sub>V</sub>*: S̲N̲<sub>agente</sub> SN<sub>tema</sub> SP<sub>alvo</sub>

A preposição usada pode ser *a* ou, mais raramente, *em* (ver o exemplo sob *depor*).

> - passar às mãos de, dar: *Entreguei-lhe a carta.*
> - restituir: *Vos ordena que lhe entregueis castelos e fortalezas e lugares e vilas que heis tomado.*
> - pagar: *Entreguei-lhe o que lhe devia*
> - confiar: *E saiu, entregando os filhos a uma cunhada, esposa do irmão morgado*
> - denunciar: *Que me quereis vós dar, e eu vo-lo entregarei?*, *Dizem que tu entregaste os ladrões ao chefe da polícia.*
> - vender: *Entregarei o lote a quem mais der*
> - depor: *Morreu, enfim, S. Gonçalo, entregando a alma na rainha dos Anjos.*
> - expressão fixa: *entregar a alma a Deus* — morrer.

O dicionário de Francisco Fernandes não inclui exemplos, mas o alvo pode ser uma oraganização:

> O projecto de lei será entregue à/na Assembleia da República.

Sob **pronominal** no dicionário:

> - render-se: *Antes querem ao mar aventurar-se que nas mãos inimigas entregar-se.*
> - confiar-se: *Muito bem. Entreguemo-nos nas mãos de Deus.* Fatalmente, a ti me entrego, o teu braço me conduz.

Nestes casos, parece-me mais discutível a natureza argumental de *se*:

> - dedicar-se: *Tendo-se entregado com fervor ao estudo, como um meio de afugentar pensamentos cruéis…*
> - dar-se, dedicar-se inteiramente: *Entregar-se à leitura dos clássicos.*
> - deixar-se possuir de: *entregar-se a vício ou paixão.* *Entegravam-se depois ao sono, nunca interrompido pelos cuidados nem pelos pesares*.

É também listada uma variante (incoativa?) em que o beneficiário passa a sujeito, o tema é introduzido por *de*, e o agente desaparece:

> tomar entrega ou posse de: *Feito pelo secretário o termo de entrega do preso, se entrega dele o alcaide*, *Fico entregue do livro, que só tive tempo de folhear*.

#### *entregar*<sub>V</sub>: S̲N̲<sub>agente</sub> SN<sub>tema</sub>

> - atraiçoar, trair: *E a Judas Iscariotes, que foi o mesmo que o entregou*, *Entregar o que nos confiou o seu segrêdo.*
> - expressões fixas: *entregar os pontos*, *entregar a rapadura com a palha e tudo* — considerar-se vencido, desanimar.

Comment: Obrigado, foi de grande ajuda sua resposta. A indicação do aulete foi ótima, tem ajudado muito este dicionário.